# Java heap space error during deployment - returns “OutOfMemoryError"

Tags: java, jvm, out-of-memory, heap-memory

I have spring app, with intelliJ (community edition), ant, tomcat 8.5. There is `build.xml` (ant) file that works for others, but in my case it gives me an error :`java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space`. 
I have already tried:

- Creating `setenv.bat` (I'm on windows) `set JAVA_OPTS=-server -Xmx1024m`.
- Then, setting `CATALINA_OPTS`/`JAVA_OPTS`/`ANT_OPTS` system env. variable to `-Xms512m -Xmx1024m`
- Then in `Configure tomcat`(GUI) -> `Java` -> `Initial memory pool` and `Maximum memory pool` to `512` and `1024`.
- Then in `idea.exe.vmoptions` (intelliJ), changed `-Xms` to `512m` and `-Xmx` to `1024m`

But it keeps giving me an error about not enough `heap space`, while other app (spring mvc as well) works perfectly fine on the same computer with the same intelliJ and the same tomcat configuration (but with maven).

I will download `JVisualVM` to get better overview what is happening but in the meantime maybe someone could give me a tip what else I could try to fix it?

Comment: Have you tried to increase the memory available (the `-Xmx` option) to, say 2048m (2G)?  How much memory does the machine have?  32 bit or 64 bit?  It is unclear where you're running out of memory - is it in Intellij or in Tomcat?

Comment: How much actual memory you have ?